# Dynamic Pagination using Angular and Bootstrap 3

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am working with AngularJS and Bootstarp3 and need some help with pagination.

I need to create pages based on amount of data I have (roughly 150,000 entries).

```
<pagination>... </pagination>
```

Doesn't work with Bootstrap 3 from my understanding.

Pages can be created using this method:

```
<ul class="pagination">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
</ul>
```

..but I need a way to add/remove the pages automatically since the number of entries in the table can change.

Comment: have you tried the example on angular bootstrap doc site ? https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/pagination

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Pagination code example](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/pagination) from the UI-Bootstrap site.

The attribute `items-per-page` defines how many items would be rendered per pagination page, the directive will do the rest and will show the right amount of pages depending on the amount of items, even after you add/remove some of them.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9m4Z3rPd1zoMJW5Ml9bY?p=preview)

Comment: I looked at it, but for some reason uib-pagination wasn't working and <pagination> started working some how...